# Delegate Method Property

Tags: c#

I made a simple delegate example to try to understand delegates. Here is the code:

```
namespace DelegateExample
{

public delegate int BinaryOp(int x, int y);

public class SimpleMath
{
    public static int Add(int x, int y) { return x + y; }
    public static int Subtract(int x, int y) { return x - y; }
    public static int Multiply(int x, int y) { return x * y; }
    public static int Divide(int x, int y) { return x / y; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("*******Simple Delegate Example************");

        BinaryOp d = new BinaryOp(SimpleMath.Multiply);
        d += SimpleMath.Divide;
        d += SimpleMath.Add;

        Display(d);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void Display(Delegate dobj)
    {
        foreach (BinaryOp del in dobj.GetInvocationList())
        {
            int ans = del.Invoke(10, 10);
            Console.WriteLine(ans);
            Console.WriteLine("Method Name: {0}", dobj.Method);              
        }
        Console.WriteLine("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
    }
}
}
```

and here is the output:

```
*******Simple Delegate Example*********
100
Method Name: Int32 Add(Int32, Int32)
1
Method Name: Int32 Add(Int32, Int32)
20
Method Name: Int32 Add(Int32, Int32)
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

My Question:
In the output, why does the .Method property return the same Name ('Add' in each case), yet the actual result returned is that of calling Multiply, Divide then Add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you made a type in your Display method:

```
Console.WriteLine("Method Name: {0}", dobj.Method);
```

When it should be:

```
Console.WriteLine("Method Name: {0}", del.Method);
```